# Display <apex:inputField values> based on the value of the first input Field salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I have a database seup like "c is a lookup to b" and "b is a lookup to a"

Example data

```
a1 has b1, b2, b3
a2 has b4, b5, b6
```

My Code

```
<apex:page standardController="c" >
    <apex:inputField value="{!c.b.a__c} />
    <apex:inputField value="{!c.b__c} />
</apex:page>
```

My question is, If I select a1 in the first inputField, I want to show only b1, b2, b3 in the second input field, not all the values in the b.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way to do that in Salesforce is by using **Dependent picklists**.
[Check the official doc out](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm)

If you can't change your data model, try [**dependent lookups**](http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_lookup_filters_dependent_lookups.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. We can achieve this using dependent picklists. But, is there any way to achieve the same using Look up fields? Because, we are not in a good position to change our database structure.

Comment: Did you see Dependent Lookups? http://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_lookup_filters_dependent_lookups.htm, It's the same idea than dependent picklists but using lookups fields

Comment: Hmm, I think Dependent Lookups are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by adding a Javascript `onblur` event, which in turn calls an `<apex:actionFunction/>` element that calls a controller method.

This method does a soql select statement to find the related data you are looking for.

You would then populate your picklist with this list data and `return null` from your method.

You would then need to select a appropriate `rerender` attribute on the `<apex:actionFunction/>` so that at least the second input field would be redrawn. Let me know if you want any more details.